# Number of editors open, except those pinned

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there a way to increase the number of editors open before closing, to not take into account the ones that are pinned?

Those that are pinnned are important, so if I put the number on 6, open 6, pin 2 then I should be able to open 2 more.

Also, close all but pinned!?

Answer (score 1):

Under General-> Editors

"When all editors are dirty or pinned" - choose open new editor

(I'm using Eclipse 3.7.2)

Comment: Try set it to 2, and then pin two. Open a third, and try now a fourth...  the third gets replaced. The pinned ones should not be counted at all.

Comment: No, sounds like open source developers implemented this feature and the rest of eclipse. my bad luck that I am forced to use it.

Comment: Well you could raise a bug on bugzilla and contribute a fix.